# how do you remove an element from a list during a conditional statement?

Tags: python

i am creating a text based adventure game with python 34 (not with pygame) and i have a class of characters. i then took these characters and split them into two lists: good, and evil. i then have a series of fights between them, but i cant figure out how to remove a character from the list if it dies. the fights are random, so a different character will win every time, meaning that i need a chunk of code to remove a character from the list depending on who wins the fight.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the index of element to be removed from your list, you can do:

```
yourlist.pop(index_of_the_element_to_be_removed)
```

If you know the value of the element to be removed from your list, you can do:

```
yourlist.pop(yourlist.index(value_of_the_element_to_be_removed))
```

If you want to remove all the elements with the value, you can do:

```
[e for e in yourlist if e!=value_of_the_element_to_be_removed]
```

Comment: Notice second line of code will remove only the first `value_of_the_element_to_be_removed` in a string.

Answer (score 0):

You can call remove() on your good list and evil list if you pass which character you are removing.

```
good_list.remove('good_guy')
```

or

```
bad_list.remove('bad_guy')
```

Comment: as Allen mentioend, you can also use list.pop()

Answer (score 0):

Based on my understanding, I tried to simulate a random one-vs-one fight for each round.

```
import random
from __future__ import print_function
characters = ['good1_fox','evil1_elephant','good2_tiger','evil2_lion','good3_bird','evil3_chicken']
# Try to split characters into two lists
good = [x for x in characters if 'good' in x]
evil = [x for x in characters if 'evil' in x]
# Total round of fight
n = 3
for i in xrange(n):
    good_fighter = random.choice(good)
    evil_fighter = random.choice(evil)
    # set the condition of winning
    if len(good_fighter) >= len(evil_fighter):
        # Remove fighter from the list
        evil.remove(evil_fighter)
        print("evil lost {} in fighting with {}".format(evil_fighter, good_fighter))    
    else:
        # Remove fighter from the list          
        good.remove(good_fighter)
        print("good lost {} in fighting with {}".format(good_fighter, evil_fighter))    
print("Remained good fighters: {}\nRemained evil fighters: {}\n".format(", ".join(good),", ".join(evil)))
```

== Printed result

good lost good2_tiger in fighting with evil1_elephant
evil lost evil2_lion in fighting with good3_bird
good lost good1_fox in fighting with evil1_elephant
Remained good fighters: good3_bird
Remained evil fighters: evil1_elephant, evil3_chicken

==
Is this what you want?